Need Help with CSC for Galaxy A15 4G
I'm currently using a Galaxy A15 4G and I've run into a bit of a snag trying to figure out the correct CSC (Country Specific Code).
When I navigate to the Software Information section under Service provider software version, I see the following details:
Service provider software version
SAOMC_SM-A155F_OJM_MID_14_0004
MID/MID,MID/XSG

However, when I check for OTA updates, the URL displayed is: https://doc.samsungmobile.com/SM-A155F/MID/doc.html.
To add to the confusion, when I used samfw.com to check the CSC, it indicated that the CSC was TUR instead of MID.
I'm a bit lost here. Could anyone please clarify which one is the correct CSC? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!
